Passing Authorization Token from Apex to Salesforce External Services method
I am using External services for integration. I've created Named Credentials, External Named Credentials, External Services Utilized Custom API.
In 1st method call I'll be getting Authentication token for my subsequent requests. How can I pass the token in header for next GET method calls from APEX. Is there anyway we can pass values from Apex to Headers.
